# Export a specific table with all its child-tables to xml

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, devexpress

I need to make reports for 5+ tables and the datasource is an xml-file that I generated using a query in my database. Now I've done this before with a small table and relatively few child-tables, but it takes a long time to find all the relations. I used this code:

```
select *, 

(select *,
    (select * from PostalCode where PostalCode.PostalCodeNumber = Customer.PostalCodeNumber for xml path ('PostalCode'), type),
    (select * from Province where Province.ProvinceCode = Customer.ProvinceCode for xml path ('Province'), type),
    (select * from Land where Land.LandCode = Customer.LandCode for xml path ('Land'), type)
from Customer where Customer.CustomerNumber = SampleRequest.CustomerNumber for xml path ('Customer'), type),

(select *,
    (select * from Article where Article.ArticleNumber = SampleRequestLine.ArticleNumber for xml path ('Article'), type)
from SampleRequestLine where SampleRequestLine.RequestNumber = SampleRequest.RequestNumber for xml path ('SampleRequestLine'), type),
(select * from Firm where Firm.FirmCode = SampleRequest.FirmCode for xml path ('Firm'), type),
(select * from CustomerDeliveryAddress where CustomerDeliveryAddress.DeliveryAddressCode = SampleRequest.DeliveryAddressCode for xml path ('DeliveryAddress'), type)
from SampleRequest
for xml path ('SampleRequest'), root ('SampleRequests')
```

[image: (screenshot of code in case the markup isn't very clear)]
Now my question is: Is there a less time-consuming way to export a specific table with all the child tables? (Maybe by using some sort of software?)

Comment: You mention that your datasource is an XML file. Is it possible to migrate these to a simple SQL database? If you did that, and then created some stored procedures, you'd cut down your query time by an immense amount.

Comment: Do you mean create a second, smaller database with only the tables I will need for the report/XML?

Comment: Possibly. I was actually thinking about your entire database, assuming you might need to do some other form of report in the future. Unless, of course, you meant that your report is generated in XML format.

Comment: If I export the entire database to an XML it will take me a long time to find the right data in devexpress as well, not to mention the size of the XML would be enormous. Lets say I need to make a report about x from a database 'alphabet' and y and z are children of x, I will need to export x,y and z to one single XML file.

Comment: So your source is an SQL database?

Comment: The actual source, yes, it's an SQL database (SQL server 2008). But I can only read data in devexpress through an XML, or I'm ordered to do so anyways.

Comment: Are you able to make a second, static database for the purposes of reporting? If you're working with XML, you're going to have a fair few problems if you try and write multiple tables to one file, particularly as there aren't any programs that I'm aware of that can read multiple tables in that fashion.

Comment: The XML's are static and are only being used for demonstration purposes only. In a later stage my colleagues will be able to link the entire database entirely to the devexpress reporting-tool. As I said I've done it successfully with a small table and the hierarchy remains the same in devexpress, as seen here http://i.gyazo.com/921a50539e0132a754aa11ee380e00ee.png . I've used software like 'Altova XMLSpy / DatabaseSpy' but they can only export the data from one single table, without the child tables.

Comment: I see. Have you tried using the bulk copy utility? From what I've read, it's a more appropriate command for large scale exports. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx and http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/239156/Export-data-from-SQL-Server-as-XML

Comment: I've seen and considered this solution before but it comes down to the same principle as my initial problem, see you have to manually join the tables as well. It wouldn't be a big problem if you only have 1 or 2 child tables but, my tables tend to have 4+ child tables and those child tables have child tables as well etc., sorry for making it so difficult. Also [basic hierarchy/multiple tables](http://i.gyazo.com/9ba989f27d7e4047eba9235757a89910.png) in XML is possible as far as I know

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11887530/3824902

Comment: This is basically the same code as I have above. My database has around 100 tables and the total amount that can be linked to 1 main table (to make a report) can be 12 tables, but to find all of them in this big mess, it is too much time absorbing per table. So no, this didn't really help, I'm looking more for software that can export all the data, taking the foreign keys in consideration or a way more efficient method. I do want to thank the effort you are putting in this.

Comment: It's fine, I get incensed by things sometimes. The only thing I can possibly think of is SolidQ, which uses a form of the BCP utility to mass export between SQL server instances. It might be possible to alter this to meet your standards... but as for recognising it... You might also be able to mould Toad to your whim, although again I'm not sure how this would work. AFAIK, toad works better exporting to an Excel spreadsheet. http://bcp2sqlazure.codeplex.com/ , http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/default.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: Thanks Wolfish for your responds, for now I'll keep doing it the hard way but I'll surely look into Toad.

Comment: You can create the XML by using [auto-generated DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171897.aspx) in Visual Studio. Just use its [`DataSet.WriteXml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135425(v=vs.110).aspx) method with `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` mode.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio, and my colleagues probably won't do this seeing as it is possible the hard way then why try to find another way. But I'll certainly let them know if I have to make more reports (for now I finished 80% of the tables the hard way, so I'll just keep doing this ;) thanks anyways)